# Azure Function batchSize

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am wondering about the parallel principle in Azure Function. If I have a batchSize of 32 and a threshold of 16. If the queue grow to large the Scale controller spins up a new function to withstand the pressure. I understand this bit. What I don't understand is: does a single instance work on the batch? That is, do I only have one function running pr batch, or does the runtime scale out and run multiple threads with the function?

Could I risk having two instances running, each with a 32 messages, and  concurrently 32 threads running 32 functions pr once?

Imaging I have a function calling a webapi. This means that the api will get 64 calls at once which I don't want.

What I want is 2 functions working on 32 messages each making 1 call pr message pr function.

I hope you guys understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is indeed how scaling works. The same is explained with a bit more details in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---concurrency) as well.

According to that, your function (one instance) could run up to 48 messages at a time (32 from a new batch + 16 from the existing batch) and could potentially scale to multiple instances depending on the queue length.

To achieve the scenario you've mentioned, you would have to

1. Set the `batchSize` to `1` to avoid parallel processing per instance
2. Set the `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` app setting to `2` to limit scale out to a max of 2 instances

Note that all 32 messages won't be loaded by either instance but will work through the queue nonetheless.